# В новом Laravel проект ошибки при запуске npm run watch

Tags: php, laravel, npm

Всем привет,
Создал новый Laravel проект

```
$ php artisan --version 
Laravel Framework 5.5.18

$ node -v
v7.10.0
$ npm -v 
4.2.0
```

Но я получил ошибки:

```
$ npm run watch

> @ watch /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/vtasks
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2017-10-23T07_18_03_617Z-debug.log
```

Но в файле 2017-10-23T07_18_03_617Z-debug.log  :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'watch' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 silly lifecycle @~prewatch: no script for prewatch, continuing
7 info lifecycle @~watch: @
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/vtasks/node_modules/.bin:/home/serge/bin:/home/serge/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/vtasks
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:33:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/vtasks
16 error Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
17 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
18 error node v7.10.0
19 error npm  v4.2.0
20 error file sh
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error syscall spawn
24 error @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
24 error spawn ENOENT
25 error Failed at the @ watch script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
25 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
25 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
25 error not with npm itself.
25 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
25 error     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
25 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
25 error     npm bugs
25 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
25 error     npm owner ls
25 error There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Я что-то упустил и как это исправить ?

Спасибо !

Comment: ссори, а `npm install` и `npm update` выполняли?

Answer (score 1):

Ответа на комментарий не получил, но попробуйте в корне проекта выполнить:

```
npm install
```

или

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю что вы пользуетесь ОС Windows

в файле package.json замените содержимое `scripts` на

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```